# customErrors mode="Off" in web.config but still Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net

I deployed an asp.net website to a shared server.....

I got the error

`Server Error in '/' Application.`

**Runtime Error**

`Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.`

Here is my page http://static3.nextgenits.com/Forms/Homepage.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the customErrors mode in directories above your application or the machine.config?  It's possible that one of these config files has a customErrors mode of RemoteOnly and an allowOverride of false, as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178693.aspx).  An administrator might have set this to prevent sensitive data from being displayed to remote clients.